# How can I change an image view in swift without any animations?

Tags: swift, animation, view

I would like to change an image view in swift but I do not want any animation with it.

The code I am using to change image view is:

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("second", sender: self)
```

How can I make my code perform the same thing (change view) but without the animation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Click on the segue arrow in your Storyboard.
2. In the *Attributes Inspector* on the right, uncheck the **Animates** checkbox.

   [image: Segue Attributes Inspector]